# Mac OS X Lion - compiling Q

Tags: macos, wget

We're installing a bunch of GNU tools and just upgraded xcode to 4.3 and downloaded and installed all the gcc tools through it.

Now we're trying to install wget, which requires a few other packges, some of which are complaining that /usr/local/share/info does not exist.

Where is the correct or preferred location for things to install under Lion / xcode? /Developer/usr/local?

I've found a number of good reference here but none that answer this specific quandary.

Suggestion greatly - GREATLY! - appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried MacPorts, which has a port for [wget](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=wget)?

Comment: This was totally the solution we used.